# Batch file extract string

Tags: string, batch-file, extract

I know this has been asked numerous times, but I've been researching for like 2 hours and still can't do that.

I need a batch script to extract a string from a file.

The content of the file is this:

> C:\Windows\system32\tasks{7D7A0547-0D79-0805-0A11-0B780D08110D}

I want to extract this part:

> {7D7A0547-0D79-0805-0A11-0B780D08110D}

I tried it with **for /f** command and all kinds of options and searches, but I just can't do it.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%# in ("C:\Windows\system32\tasks{7D7A0547-0D79-0805-0A11-0B780D08110D}") do echo {%%#}
```

?

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much to both of you. Both scripts work perfectly. I know what the token is, can you just explain to me why we using 2 tokens here? And the delims command, what is it used for? Is it some separator where to look for something?

Comment: @TwinHeadedEagle - yes delims is a separator and there you can list symbols (words cannot work as delimiters - default delimters are `space`,`tab`,`=`,`;`,`,`). As here we have two delimiters the first part of the splitted string will be the part before `{` and the second between the `{ and }` - so we are taking the second token

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%A in (
  'findstr "{[0-9A-F-]*}" "X:\path\yourfile.ext" '
) Do Echo %%A
```